# What is the bios eeprom brand and model on Asus proart x670e creator wifi motherboard?

Tags: bios, motherboard, asus, eeprom

I want to answer because I have to know before buying that since it supports for mountable eeprom it helps to reflash or reprogram the bios using bios programmer with clip on eeprom while the bios is being corrupted by power cut or wrong way of updating bios.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the content of EEPROM is corrupted it can be reprogrammed, just need to get it out of motherboard. I personally can't believe the EEPROM chip is corrupted.

Comment: Are you asking if it has an EEPROM vs. an EPROM?

Comment: that board has bios flashback *feature* so, should be able to flash bios even after a corrupted flash - I say *should* - but it is an ASUS board, so chances are about 50/50

Comment: "What is the bios eeprom brand and model"  How in the world would we know the answer, contact Asus support.